# Can i use sata adapter for more memory for gaming?

Tags: sata, build

my old laptop broke and my new one has only 32 gb of memory. My old laptop had 750 gb hdd. If i connect my old laptops hd to my new laptop via sata cable will i be able to save games to it via steam and play them? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by 'memory' you mean storage, not RAM.

Yes, you can connect the old laptop's disk through a SATA⇆USB adapter and it'll be usable with Steam – although you should make sure both the adapter and the port are USB 3, otherwise it might be too slow for some games.

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky (owner of some HP laptop that has combined eSATA/USB port)  then you need only a eSATA cable for that (2-5 bucks) and it will give you the same transfer speed as an internal hdd. If you will get USB2<->SATA adapter  then you will be limited to a maximum speed 30-38 Mbytes/s, so make sure you have USB3(blue one) on new laptop and make sure then to get UBS3<->SATA adapter to get compatible with SATA speed